# R - Plot correctness of answers of every single question of a questionnaire using multiple factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got data from a questionnaire of students of different school types. The questionnaire contains 14 questions (0=false, 1=right) and there are 4 different school types. I am now trying to plot the average correctness of every question by school type. I thought that I could plot the questions continous on the x-axis maybe as bars.

The data looks like:

| Nr | School type | Quest1 | Quest2 | Quest3 | Quest4 | Quest5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Primary | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Secondary | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | Higher | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | Secondary | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | Primary | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | Primary | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | Higher | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | Secondary | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your question about the best way to visualize this data or ow to create a specific type of plot from the data using `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this approach can be useful:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(-School.type) %>%
  group_by(School.type,name) %>%
  summarise(Avg=mean(value==1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=Avg,fill=School.type))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(0.9),color='black')+
  theme_bw()+xlab('Question')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(School.type = c("Primary", "Secondary", "Higher", 
"Secondary", "Primary", "Primary", "Higher", "Secondary"), Quest1 = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Quest2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L), Quest3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Quest4 = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Quest5 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the questions arent in the right order. Is there a possibility to fix that?

Comment: @JustusBlaschke Which order do you want? Could you please tell me?

Comment: From Question 1 to Question 5. In the actual data the plots starts with Question 1 than goes to Question 10-13 followed by Question 2-9. Thank you!

Comment: @JustusBlaschke Just add this code before the group_by line `mutate(name=factor(name),levels=unique(name),ordered=T) %>%`